# Give over an inheriting class as a parameter which wishes the inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, parameters

Okay, I tried to put my problem/question in one sentence in the title. I have the following code example:

```
    class ParentClass
{

};

//#include "ParentClass_Header.h"
class SomeOtherClass
{
    ParentClass* parent;
public:
    virtual void func(ParentClass* parentclass) {
        parent = parentclass;
    }
};

class ChildClass : public ParentClass
{
public:
};

void SomeOtherClass::func(ChildClass* childclass)
{

}
```

Anyway, I have a ParentClass which I inherited to a ChildClass. Another (SomeOtherClass) class has to hold some information about the ChildClass (the pointer is needed in the function SomeOtherClass:func(...)).

The compiler says something like the ChildClass* cannot be converted in ParentClass*. I don't think it is possible to do this the way I am trying to do it. The other way would be to declare a ChildClass* child_ptr and assign it with child_ptr = this in any member function (of class ChildClass). But it would be nice to know if there is another, maybe more professional way.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration and definition of `func` are different, in the class declaration you give it an argument of `ParentClass *` whilst you define it with a `ChildClass*`. If you only want for it to take a `ChildClass*` as an argument then declare it as such, or vice-versa if you would like the function to take any derived `ParentClass*`.

I would say however judging by your naming of "Child" and "Parent" that the code seems confused with its aim. It is not normal that a child would be derived from a parent, instead you would expect the parent class to have some form of container that managed the children. In this case one should pass the parent in the constructor if the child needs to communicate backwards to the parent.